# Failing test while trying to mock Entity Framework with MOQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, moq

I am writing an ASP.NET console application to practice mocking Entity Framework with MOQ for testing. The app manages a book store and has a basic `EditPrice` method as shown below:

```
public class BookStore
{
    private BookContext context;

    public BookStore(BookContext newContext)
    {
        context = newContext;
    }

    // Edit the price of a book in the store
    public Book EditPrice(int id, double newPrice)
    {
        Book book = context.Books.Single(b => b.Id == id);
        book.Price = newPrice;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return book;
    }
}
```

This method is tested with the following test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_EditPrice()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Book>>();

        var mockContext = new Mock<BookContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Books).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new BookStore(mockContext.Object);
        service.AddBook(1, "Wuthering Heights", "Emily Brontë", "Classics", 7.99, 5);

        // Act
        service.EditPrice(1, 5.99);

        // Assert
        mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Book>()), Times.Once());
        mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Exactly(2));
    }
```

This method fails throwing the following error:

> Message: Test method BookStoreNonCore.Tests.NonQueryTests.Test_EditPrice threw exception:
>   System.NotImplementedException: The member 'IQueryable.Provider' has not been implemented on type 'DbSet'1Proxy' which inherits from 'DbSet`1'. Test doubles for 'DbSet'1' must provide implementations of methods and properties that are used.

Following along with the debugger, the test fails on the line in the main `EditPrice` method

```
Book book = context.Books.Single(b => b.Id == id);
```

I haven't quite got to grips with mock testing yet and am not sure why this is failing. Would anyone be able to explain and provide a solution?

Comment: Error message is clear! you have not provided implementation for `DbSet` members like Single, SingleOrDefault, Add, Remove etc. I am somewhat busy otherwise I could have helped you more. Hope some will help you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember mocking entity framework in this way is VERY difficult, I suggest that if you are very adamant about testing the framework in this way then it may be better to wrap your context in an interface `IBookContext` and have your own methods wrapping the functionality of entity framework so that things are more easily moqable and you don't have to deal with entity framework.

- If you are using .Net core then there is an InMemory provider that you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/
- If you are using the framework then there is a testing framework called Effort: https://entityframework-effort.net/

Both are in memory implementations of entity framework - you can use these in tests so you don't have to integrate with a database (which is slow)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using a Linq query rather than the Single member:

```
    // Edit the price of a book in the store
    public void EditPrice(int id, double newPrice)
    {
        var query = from book in context.Books
                    where book.Id == id
                    select book;

        Book BookToEdit = query.ToList()[0];
        BookToEdit.Price = newPrice;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Then followed the example on this website for Testing Query Scenrios

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking

to write this test method which now works:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_EditPrice()
    {
        // Arrange
        var data = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book(1, "Wuthering Heights", "Emily Brontë", "Classics", 7.99, 5)
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Book>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<BookContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Books).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        // Act
        var service = new BookStore(mockContext.Object);
        var books = service.GetAllBooks();
        service.EditPrice(1, 5.99);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(data.Count(), books.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("Wuthering Heights", books[0].Title);
        Assert.AreEqual(5.99, books[0].Price);
    }
```

Thank you to both of you for pointing me in the right direction (or at least away from the cause of the problem).

Comment: Love this. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I recall that when using a Mock I ran into problems when testing asynchronous EF operations.

To fix that you can distill an interface from your DbContext and create a second "Fake" DbContext. This Fake could contain a number of FakeDbSet classes (inheriting DbSet).

Check out this MS documentation, more specifically the part "Testing with async queries":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestingDemo
{
    internal class TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IDbAsyncQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

        internal TestDbAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
        {
            _inner = inner;
        }

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
        }

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
        }

        public object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            return _inner.Execute(expression);
        }

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
        }

        public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Execute(expression));
        }

        public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
        }
    }

    internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
    {
        public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
            : base(enumerable)
        { }

        public TestDbAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
            : base(expression)
        { }

        public IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
        {
            get { return new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this); }
        }
    }

    internal class TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

        public TestDbAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
        {
            _inner = inner;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _inner.Dispose();
        }

        public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return _inner.Current; }
        }

        object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }
    }
}
```

The FakeDbSet class needs to have a few overrides to return these different implementations, also mentioned in the documentation:

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<Blog>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
    .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<Blog>(data.GetEnumerator()));

mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>()
    .Setup(m => m.Provider)
    .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<Blog>(data.Provider));

mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
```

Except instead of setting this up in a Mock, it's just a method override in your own class.

The advantage of this is that you can set up fake data in your unit tests in a more compact and readable way than setting up mocks and fake returns. For example:

```
[TestClass]
public class BookTest 
{
    private FakeBooksDbContext context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        context = new FakeBooksDbContext();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void When_PriceIs10_Then_X()
    {
        // Arrange
        SetupFakeData(10);

        // Act

        // Assert
    }

    private void SetupFakeData(int price) 
    {
        context.Books.Add(new Book { Price = price });
    }
}
```

In EFCore, all of this is irrelevant and you can just use an in-memory database type of course.

Comment: I've been using this pattern for a while now, but after I updated Moq from 4.7.1 to 4.14.5 it stopped working with this error "The member 'IQueryable.Provider' has not been implemented on type 'DbSet`1Proxy' which inherits from 'DbSet`1'. Test doubles for 'DbSet`1' must provide implementations of methods and properties that are used.". Any ideas?

Comment: Correction! It was Castle.Core version 4.4.0 that created the issue, updating to 4.4.1 resolved it. :-)